# Using Hashids to protect the id in database

Tags: node.js, express, hashids

People get the data from url like `http://domain/api/user/1` and the `1` is the `id`(primary key) in the database. We want to avoid this to prevent people detect the ids.

Then I found [Hashids](http://hashids.org/node-js/) which can encode/decode the id to string, the url may change to `http://domain/api/user/D42dhDLdk`

It is a wonderful solution at the first glance, however how to use it in the real application?

1 encode

When records are retrieved from the database, we should encode the id to string, which is the right place to do this job?  The only right place I can thought is the deserialization of the records, for example, when you serve data of `json`, you can encode the related `ids` to string, but you have to make sure which fields should be encoded.

For example:

```
{user:{id:1,name:'xx',projects:[{id:1,name:'p1',id:2,name:'p2'}]},icon_id:1}}
```

The `id` of the `user` `project` and the `icon_id` should be encoded, there are no clear rules to abstract that.

2 decode

You have to decode the string to id when retrieve the data from db, I think we can do this in the `route` or `controller` layer, however there are still no clear rules to make a abstract middleware to hanlde this, since the `encoded string` may exist in the url or the query params.

I have not find any general solution from google, so I wonder how do you handle this kind of problem?

---

Update:

I am using Mysql, and Express with sequelzie as the ORM tool.

Comment: What DB are you using and do you use any middleware between the server and your DB

Comment: So why don't you use the hashed ID instead of ID from db. I mean just create new hashid and save it to db. There's no need to encode/decode it. Simply save it to db and use it as primary key.

Comment: @Molda wouldn't that require tracking an autoincrementing value somewhere outside of the database? Since you need to know what the "next" id is going to be (and preferably in a way that allows multiple concurrent writers).

Comment: @DerTieran: I have updated my post.  And robertklep is right.

Comment: Well you can use probably something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid to get unique ID without need for keeping track of some autoincrement value. Try Google *nodejs unique id generator* for some alternatives

Comment: @Molda: Oh, I love this `Can generate any number of ids without duplicates, even millions per day.`, but I still wonder how can it make sure there will be no duplicates as long as the application runs?

Comment: @hguser Time in microseconds + maybe some random string and the chance you get same ID in the exactly same microsecond is pretty low I think.